# QueryDict getlist returns empty list

Tags: django

I'm sending from frontend object with one property which equal to array.

In backend I need to get data from that array.

when i write **request.POST** i see:

```
<QueryDict: {u'response[0][doc_id]': [u'14'], u'response[1][uuid]': [u'157fa2ae-802f-f851-94ba-353f746c9e0a'], u'response[1][doc_id]': [u'23'], u'response[1][data][read][user_ids][]': [u'9'], u'response[0][uuid]': [u'8a0b8806-4d51-2344-d236-bc50fb923f27'], u'response[0][data][read][user_ids][]': [u'9']}>
```

But when **i write request.POST.getlist('response')** or **request.POST.getlist('response[]')** i get

```
[]
```

**request.POST.get('response')** doesn't work as well (returns None).

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you don't have either `response[]` or `response` as keys, you have the literal strings `response[0][doc_id]` and `response[1][uuid]` etc.

If you want to use a structure like this, you should send JSON rather than form-encoded data and access `json.loads(request.body)`.